# jquery stop() not working when combining jquery fade and slide jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I used the following javascript:

```
$('.slide-content #show-effect-1').hover(function(){
  $(this).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: _duration, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').show('slide', { direction: "down" }, _duration);
},
function() {
  $(this).next().stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: _duration, queue: false }).hide('slide', { direction: "down" }, _duration);
});
```

What should happen is:

- `mouseenter` the button --> content show
- `mouseout` the button --> content hide

Question: when `mouseout` on the button is faster than the effect time of `mouseenter`, the content will be hidden and not displayed when `mousenter` the button again.

How do I prevent this happening?

Comment: can you share the html also... possibly a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: hi Arun P Johny,
Please view this
http://jsfiddle.net/4S9Sj/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate funcitons for the fadeIn and slide effect I decided to implement both in a single `animate()` function, then I just added some CSS resets to make sure the element is ready before starting the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _duration = 1000;
    $('#show-effect-1').hover(function () {
        var $next = $('.text-banner');
        $next.show();
        $next.stop(true, true).css({
            'margin-left': $next.outerWidth() * -1,
                'margin-top': 0,
                'opacity': 0,
                'display': 'block'
        }).animate({
            'margin-left': 0,
                'opacity': 1
        }, _duration);
    }, function () {
        var $next = $('.text-banner');
        $next.stop(true, true).animate({
            'margin-top': $next.height() * -1,
                'opacity': 0
        }, _duration, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

**Check the [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4S9Sj/5/)**

Note that I had to add a container to accurately reproduce the slide effect, you can test without it and see if it's something you actually need

Comment: @SunStormSun if the answer was helpful please consider upvoting and/or marking it as accepted (click the green check mark next to it), read this for more info on accepting answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235